# create textblock programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to create textblock programmatically
But it seems the code behind file don't build it.

**EDIT**

Inside Main.cs

```
    public Main()
    {
            InitializeComponent();


    }

 public void generateUI(TypeOne item)
        {
  // Create first element
            TextBlock authorText = new TextBlock();
            authorText.Text = "Saturday Morning";
            authorText.FontSize = 12;
            authorText.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            gridUI.Children.Add(authorText);
}
```

Inside Main.xml

```
    <Page.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainWindowViewModel/>

    </Page.DataContext>
 <Grid Width="Auto" Background="WhiteSmoke" x:Name="grid">
              <Grid x:Name="gridUI" Margin="0,68,0,-37">

              </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Inside MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
            Main genUI = new Main();

            IEnumerable<TypeOne> generateUI = //query variable
                    from x in _txnType
                    where x.Description == selectedTypeOne
                    select x;

            foreach (TypeOne ui in generateUI)
            {

                genUI.generateUI(ui);
            }
```

But the  public void generateUI(TypeOne item) not creating the textblock.
I supposed, the Main.xml cannot read it since the DataContext is set to MainViewModel.cs

Please help.

Comment: ViewModel should contain only business logic. It should not have any code related to UI. Your code is in complete violation of MVVM principles.

Comment: My UI is dynamic. How UI defined is in my database. Every value means something.

Comment: Point is still valid. ViewModel should not know about UI stuff. Dynamic XAML load is responsibility of UI and should be handled in UI layer only.

Comment: Read about DataTemplates instead.

Comment: how can u do it if the values that indicate how UI should be presented are in database? obviously this should be done programmatically.  If you have a better idea, pls elaborate.

Comment: @momokjaaaaa regardless if the UI is defined in the ViewModel it is not MVVM. Basically you can't say that you implemented it properly using MVVM .

Comment: @eandersson then how to do it properly in MVVM? and can u pls tell me why my edited solution isn't working? Ppl keep telling me this is not MVVM, ok I got it. But none showed me how to do it properly.

Comment: Well. The problem  is really your question. You are asking how to do it using MVVM. If you are looking for a different answer, either edit your answer, or open a new question.

Comment: @eandersson question has been edited. Thanks for pointing that out. Should just scrap that MVVM and start getting answers from ppl.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you want to follow the MVVM pattern doesn't exclude dynamic view creation. However I always recommend that you use "logic-only" in the view model. That means that the VM still only contains logic for the view to interact with, **but has absolutely no knowledge about the view and how it behaves**.

Your view is the one using the view model and should adapt the view dynamically. This means that in the code-behind of your view, you have access to your view model and can customize the view according to your current view model. You can respond to changes in the view model as well since the view model will implement INotifyPropertyChanged (which you can intercept in your code-behind just as normal bindings would).

The question you should ask yourself is whether MVVM is the right patter for you here. If the UI always comes from a database, then where are the bindings defined? Also in the database? If so, what actual logic are you implementing in the view model? In other words: what is the point of a VM if there is no custom logic. In that case I recommend to use the view-only approach. If you need custom logic, use the approach with the code-behind I described above.

Comment: Can you please read my edited question. I changed the view creation at Main.cs but the textblock cannot be created, still. I think this is how it should work in MVVM pattern.

Comment: You are still referencing views from the view model. The whole idea of MVVM is that the VM has absolutely no knowledge about the view. I still refer to the previous answer given. First check for yourself if you actually need custom logic.